# Smooth image of a zero measure set is of measure zero

Tags: calculus, diffeomorphism

I'm trying to proof that given a diffeomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, the image of a set of measure zero, is also a set of measure zero.

I've seen several answers to similar questions here before, but unfortunately at the specific course I'm doing at the moment, we are required to talk about sets of measure zero using boxes, namely sets of the form $$[a_1,b_1]\times\dots\times[a_n,b_n]$$

So assuming my set is bounded for the moment, I know I can think of the set $E$ as a subset of some compact set containing it. So generally speaking, I know that $f$ must be Lipshitz for some constant $M$ so: $$\lVert f(\vec{x})-f(\vec{y})\rVert\leq\lVert \vec{x}-\vec{y}\rVert$$

Now, since $E$ is of measure-zero, our definition says that given some $\varepsilon>0$ we have a countable collection $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ whose union covers $A$ and the sum of the volumes is less than $\varepsilon$.

I was trying to use that to show that $f(E\cap A_i)$ is contained is a box with a volume bounded by $M{\rm Vol}\left(A_i\right)$, and this will finish the proof, but I'm somehow stuck. I can show the set is bounded inside some ball of radius $\max\limits_{i=1,\dots,n}b_i-a_i$ but I can't make it proportional to the volume.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The rough idea (I don't wish to think about all the constants exactly right now) is that a ball is always contained in a larger rectangule. say you're in 2d and you have a rectangle of lengths $a, b$, and you set $r$ to be the maximum. Then the ball of radius $r$ is definitely contained inside the rectangle of length $100a, 100b$ (again I'm too lazy to think of a better bound, you couls probably use 2a,2b or sth but hey if it works for 100, then why not). Now you can relate this to a multiple of the volume of the original rectangle.

Comment: So, my claim is that if you have a ball in $\Bbb{R}^n $, of radius equal to maximum sidelength of a given rectangle, then there ia a constant $k$ (which perhaps depends only of the dimension of the space, and not on the particular ball or rectangle) such that the ball is contained inside the rectangle of sidelengths $k$ times the original length. i.e the volume of a rectangle increasea atmost by a factor of (Lipschitz constant) ($k^n$)(volume of original rectangle). This should be enough to conclude.

Comment: Yes I see your point, I'll try to find a convincing bound for that rectangle. Thank you!

Comment: actually I'm not so sure what I said previously works, because rectangles have different side lengths, so the constant k probably depends on the rectangle. But for a square everything works out nicely I believe, and we can take the constant to be $2\sqrt{n}$ I believe.

Comment: Can you appeal to the Vitali covering theorem?